# Wordpress Gallery plugin dos not allow to download in safari and iphones

Tags: php, wordpress

Use this https://wordpress.org/plugins/photo-gallery/ plugin to my site this plugin give facility to download image in Gallery it work fine in Mozilla and  chrome as well as android mobiles but when i open this photo gallery in safari  or iPhone this image is open in new window instead of downloading